# Считать из строки число:

Tags: java, format

Здравствуйте, есть строка: `3.541250000000E+02-2.016187274636E-01-8.194984211129E-09` в ней записаны числа ( возможно несколько таких чисел, они не разделены пробелом!), числа формата 3D19.12 ( так же хотелось бы узнать про этот формат немного полезной информации)

Помогите на **java** считать из нее числа:

```
3.541250000000E+02

-2.016187274636E-01

-8.194984211129E-09
```

Я сделал поиск до E и дальше дописывал 3 символа оставшиеся, но думаю это не правильно. А как правильно?

Возможно ли это сделать на `java стримах`?

Answer (score 1):

`3D19.12` - это описание типа из Фортрана, который означает 3 числа двойной точности с отведением 19 символов под каждое, из которых 12 позиций - символы после запятой. На основании этого можно делить строчку на части и парсить отдельно.

Comment: после точки 12 символов, а что означает 3числа двойной точности? это что то типо числа до точки, после точки и после E?

Comment: @МаксимСавельев Двойной точности - это `Double`, т. е. 64 бита на число. Подробнее: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: я имею в виду 3 числа это что?)

Comment: @МаксимСавельев это значит, что в строке 3 разных числа

Comment: в строке может быть и одно число 3.541250000000E+02